# Android Date in ActionBar

Tags: android, date, android-actionbar

I am making ActionBar in Android Development. And I want to put in ActionBar this DateFormat code :

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
```

How I can put this DateFormat in my ActionBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `setTitle()`, from ActionBar.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
actionBar.setTitle(dateString);
```

Comment: @user222776 You should accept this answer if it has helped you